# Can angular cli use flag icon css?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I am beginner in angular cli and I was wondering: can I use  this https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css in package.json because when there is an update it's more easy to update automatically and I don't have to do it manually. And is it a problem that Flag icon are SCSS and I use SASS in my angular 2 project?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes it can do,

Using the package from node_modules works just fine. You'll just have to override all paths.

I've got this in my style.scss.

```
$flag-icon-css-path: '~flag-icon-css/flags' !default;
@import "~flag-icon-css/sass/flag-icon";

$image_path: '~material-design-lite/src/images' !default;
@import "~material-design-lite/src/material-design-lite";
```

Comment: this could also bring you some insights: https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/issues/586

Answer (score 16):

Installation:

```
npm install flag-icon-css --save
```

Updating the styles section in the angular.json file (if you use Angular < 6.0.0 - then angular-cli.json):

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css",
    .....
],
```

Use in templates:

```
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ru"></span>
```

Comment: Instead of editing `angular-cli.json` you could also add `@import '~flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min';` to `styles.scss`.

Comment: It's not longer what Halfist proposed by `@import '~flag-icon-css/css/flag-icons.min.css';` in flag-icon-css v4.0.0